# Android Tab Bar: Access Current Tab Activity

Tags: android, tabbar, tabactivity

I have created a custom tabbar in my application (using `TabHost` and `TabWidget`). However in my `TabActivity` I want to invoke a method of the `Activity` that is currently selected.
Here is a sample of how I initialize the tab bar:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbar);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent content;
        Button tabView;
        TabSpec tab;

        content = new Intent(this, Test1.class);
        tabView = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        tabView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_tableft_selector));
        tabView.setText("Test1");
        tabView.setTypeface(font);
        tabView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tabView.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 0);
        tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("test1").setIndicator(tabView).setContent(content);
        tabHost.addTab(tab);

        ...
    }
```

My problem is that in my `TabActivity` and in all 3 tabs I want to receive LocationUpdates, but I need to do some validation before delivering the location updates to the tab's `Activity`.
What I wanted to do is receive location updates in my `TabActivity`, do the processing and then invoke some method in the current tab `Activity`, however I can't access it from the tabHost. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they are all activities then you can use the ActivityGroup stuff since TabActivity extends ActivityGroup. You will need to define a location interface or something that all your activities implement to avoid crashes, or do checks. Also if your not too far along yet you should consider using the compatibility library and using fragments, as tabactivity and activitygroup have been deprecated

```
 LocalActivityManager m = getLocalActivityManager();
 ((LocationInterface)m.getCurrentActivity()).sendLocation();
```

Comment: thanks, i will try it this week an let you know if it's working as I needed :)

Comment: it worked exactly as I needed :) thanks bro. Do you know any good tutorial on implementing TabActivity using the Fragments API?

Comment: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/ give that a try although after looking through it I would say you could simplify it a bit without a tabhost. just using buttons or something. but a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will try that after this sprint. Regarding my post, can I access all 3 activities, instead of just the current?

Comment: just the current one. You can however use the getActivity method to access the other activities the issue is all activities must have a unique id and am not sure you would know the ids of the other two tabs.

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to call sendLocation() to all activities, but solved it using a OnTabChangeListener() and forcing a sendLocation() with the last location on a tab change ;) It's more cleaner this way. Thanks a lot for your help bro.